# Left join returning all the results even when the condition is not satisfied

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a simple query

```
select * 
from employees as e 
left join email_notification as en 
on e.id=en.eid and en.`status` != 'SUCCESS';
```

Now I have one record in email_notification table 
that has status success but still that record is getting fetched from employee table.

Comment: How about inner join? same result?

Comment: That query should return every record from `employees`.

Comment: this is how left joins work. you want an `inner join`.

Comment: @RubahMalam Inner join is worse, it eats up all the records. i.e. it doesn't return anything because my email_notification table has only one record and that too has state success to ultimately 0 records are returned.

Comment: @Uueerdo Inner join is worse, it eats up all the records. i.e. it doesn't return anything because my email_notification table has only one record and that too has state success to ultimately 0 records are returned

Comment: @leeor Inner join is worse, it eats up all the records. i.e. it doesn't return anything because my email_notification table has only one record and that too has state success to ultimately 0 records are returned

Comment: @leeor All employees that do not have a successful notification sent out.

Comment: @Uueerdo I am trying to find employees who never had a notification or had 'FAILED' or 'WAITING' status but want to skip the ones that got email notification successfully

Comment: How about employees that never receive email notifications? Exclude from resultset?

Comment: Please add some sample data and the desired result to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to left join employees to "successes" and choose those who do not have one, like so:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM employees AS e 
LEFT email_notification AS en 
ON e.id=en.eid and en.`status` = 'SUCCESS'
WHERE en.id IS NULL
;
```

Comment: I want to ignore the successes and just get employees who doesn't have one or has a 'Failed' or 'Waiting' one

Comment: I agree with you, that's why I'm trying to ask him which is the domain of the `status` field. :-)

Comment: @john.p.doe Ignoring successes is exactly what this does. The WHERE portion removes those employees that had successes. Now, if you want employees that have 'failed', 'waiting' (or some other "not success" state), that is different that employees without 'success'; in fact, it is the inner join everyone initially suggested.

Comment: @Uueerdo My friend you are some kind of a genius. I still dont understand the query fully but it did the trick.. Thanks a lot.. I never knew having a negative condition in JOIN was so tricky.

Comment: @john.p.doe LEFT JOIN gets everything from the left table, and anything from the right that the ON condition is true for. The WHERE, processes after the JOIN (mostly), removes the stuff that had matches.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't try using `IN`?

```
select * 
from employees as e 
where id not in(
    select eid from email_notification 
    where status != 'SUCCESS'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean:

```
select *
from employees as e
left join email_notification as en
on e.id=en.eid
where en.`status` != 'SUCCESS';
```

I mean, the check on `status` should not be done along with the `join`, instead it takes part on the final result.

Comment: Uhm... Are you sure that the `status` field contains the uppercased word `SUCCESS`? What about the same query without the `where` clause?

Comment: Without where clause it returns everything

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure, I was referring to the `status` field. Try that one: `select distinct status from email_notification `. Which are the returned values?

Comment: So, the query above returns the sole `SUCCESS`? That means that all the rows have the `status` field set to `SUCCESS`. Did you really try it before to reply?

Comment: Wait. There exists a record within `en` for each `id` from `e`? Otherwise, you failed to describe correctly the problem.